# Which is more accurate? Google Webmaster or Google Analytics

Tags: google, seo, google-analytics, google-search-console

I see differences between Google Analytics and Google Webmaster Tools. Why are they different and which is more accurate. How can i interpret data from both correctly?

Answer (score 2):

Google Analytics only works for visitors running javascript, that also wait for your javascript to load and communicate with Google.

This would exclude most bots and people who did not want to wait for your page to load.

Webmaster tools on the other hand also shows information about how a site performs in the search result pages.

I personally think the analytics data is more useful.

Comment: how about semrush? do you know about it. are their data relevant?

Comment: semrush seems to be about getting guesses about the traffic of your competitors, probably similar to alexa. If you want information about your own sites, go with the google tools

Comment: I think with google analytics you can now use images for tracking thereby removing the need for javascript?

Answer (score 1):

This is a bit like wondering why your Gmail, Google Voice and Google Wave inboxes all contain somewhat different messages.

Google Analytics and Webmaster Tools aren't directly comparable. They do different things. At any rate, both use approximate data and this can be dicey when the overall volume is low and estimations are difficult.

Answer (score 0):

Google analytic tool is better which gives in-depth information about your visitors.

It provides in depth details about users behavior in your website, You can use this data to analyze and improve your website's sales or objective.

In Goolge web master, you get SEO related data such as 
Keywords' Impression & position & Clicks details.

Google web master tool is mainly useful to get bird view of your organic traffic from Google. But, Analytic provides much more information about visitors.